# Azuracast/Docker/413 Request entity too large

Tags: wordpress, docker, dockerfile, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I installed Azuracast to my VPS and also installed Wordpress for my website. Both installed very nicely using Docker and the install instructions Azuracasts documentation provided. Now my only problem is that I am unable to upload the theme I purchased for the website. I am a total newbie when it comes to tinkering Docker images/containers. I have tracked the problem down and it is most likely the nginx-proxy. I need a super simplified instructions how to add client_max_body_size to the .conf file where it needs to be put. So any kind of assistance regarding this problem will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Providing you are using the default azuracast docker setup, one of the simplest way of doing it is to overwrite the **/etc/nginx/azuracast.conf** file in your **docker-compose.yml** file

```
version: '2.2'
 
services:   
  nginx_proxy:
    ...
    volumes:
      ...
      - ./azuracast.nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/azuracast.conf
```

And in your **azuracast.nginx.conf** *(you can name it anything you want)* change the 2nd line representing the max body size as such:

```
server_tokens off;
client_max_body_size 2050m;
gzip on;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_disable "msie6";
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_min_length 1100;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types
    text/plain
    text/css
    text/js
    text/xml
    text/javascript
    application/javascript
    application/x-javascript
    application/json
    application/xml
    application/xml+rss;
```

Hope this helps, well, hope you found the answer before.

For an official answer go to https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy -- but it's a bit more complicated.

Another tip: **docker-compose exec nginx_proxy bash** and **apk add nano** and have fun ;)